# calculate Mean from means of different sizes

Tags: mean, weighted-mean

So, I have multiple lists of data of different sizes. I'm calculating the average of each list. So, I have the average of each list with the total number of elements in that list.
Now I need to calculate the average of all lists. Is there a correct way to do this? I know that adding up the averages and dividing on the number of lists is correct only if all the lists are of the same size.

Comment: What is the average supposed to mean? **1** The average of the averages of lists **2** The average of the individual data points in the lists?

Comment: Example of the first case. You could be after the average of running performance of some group of people. For each person in the group you have a list of performances. Then you are not after the average of those individual performances (which is what is being computed in the answer).

Answer (score 0):

Just after I posted the question I found the Weighted Mean. I didn't know about it before.
So, I have the means of the lists, then I divide the size of each list by the sum of all sizes to get the weight for each mean.
Then I sum them all to get the weighted mean which is the correct one.

Comment: Follows two other references that I hope may help you to understand this problem from a bayesian point of view: [Of Bayesian average and star ratings](https://fulmicoton.com/posts/bayesian_rating/) and [Bayesian Average Ratings](http://www.evanmiller.org/bayesian-average-ratings.html)

Comment: @xboard thanks for the readings. It added to my knowledge